# One that I think is a problem with transportation / What I think is a problem with transportation - Are both of them possible?

Tags: sentence-construction

Q: What are some problems with transportation in your country?

A:

> 1. ***One that I think is a problem with transportation*** is that we have to deal with the stress of wasting our time on the roads during rush hour.
> 2. ***Something else that I think is a problem with transportation*** is that air is getting polluted because of the exhaust gas.

I feel I can use these sentences but I'm not sure enough to say in front of others. Can I use both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have (almost!) the same pattern here:

```
[One XXX]  
    [that I think is a problem with transportation]  
[is that...]

[Something else]  
    [that I think is a problem with transportation]  
[is that...]
```

So if you look at the two closely you'll note that in the first example something is missing: The **what**. Terms like *thing*, *aspect* or similar come to mind.

The pattern works, but is - as far as style is concerned - quite cumbersome. Especially for the first I'd suggest a simpler

> One problem with transportation is...

(You don't necessarily have to point out that you are expressing your thoughts.)